# App store to forget programs on Iphone 6s

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

Over the past few years, I have downloaded various apps onto my iPhone from the App Store. I have noticed that the App Store remembers the apps that I have downloaded. So, for instance: If I download an app and then delete it from my phone and go back into the App Store, the download icon is different (it doesn't say "+Get" like apps that I have never downloaded before, instead it will have an icon of a cloud with an arrow pointing downwards).

How to I get the App Store to forget these programs?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what *you* mean by "forget these programs", but you can choose to hide them.

To hide apps you can:

1. Open the App Store app
2. Tap on **Updates > Purchased > My Purchases**
3. Find the app that you want to hide
4. Swipe left on the app
5. Tap *Hide*

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  All apps associated with an Apple ID will be displayed.

The only reason (that I'm aware) that an app will not be displayed is if the app is no longer for sale in the store (the developer discontinued the app, for example).

If you don't want to see these apps, you'll need to create a new Apple ID.  This might be more trouble than it's worth, however.  Switching to a new Apple ID will affect **everything** associated with that ID such as iCloud, Game Center, past in-app purchases, etc.  I'm not talking about just changing your email address, I'm referring to moving to a brand new Apple ID.

If you decide this path is worth it for you, just sign-out of every service and device on the old ID and create a new Apple ID.  Then sign-in with that new ID on all your devices and services.